# Identity: Authentication in Two Different asp.net mvc5 Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have two different `asp.net mvc5` application in a same solution but for the authenticate I use different tables. When I execute the application and login in one of them, the other application takes the user who is authenticated in first application.

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this?

Comment: because are two different application and use different users, one is the administrator and the other application is for user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of authentication cookie: when user authenticate himself in first project, it creates the cookie, then second project receives and accepts the cookie. Try to change default auth cookie name in web.config files.

Comment: When i put this `code`<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="DeveloperAuthenticationCookiename" loginUrl="Account/Login"/>`code`
    </authentication> nothing hapend i have the same problem

Comment: Would you please catch your browser traffic in dev console (F12 in any browser) and make sure that cookie names are different in both projects?

Comment: Both are DeveloperAuthenticationCookiename? Did you change one web.config or both?

Comment: The names listed are ASP.NETSessionId cookies and .ASPNET.ApplicationCookie appears nowhere in DeveloperAuthenticationCookiename

Comment: Oh, my bad. I missed that this is a OWIN project. Instead of web.config, go ahead to Startup.Auth.cs, find where you setup cookie authentication (look for app.UseCookieAuthentication) and put different CookieName for each project.